# CLI/ANGULAR16: Fail to load the testing environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to load a testing environment when I launch ng test.

angular.json:

```
{
  "build": {
    "configurations": {
       // ...
       "test": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.testing.ts"
          }
        ]
      }
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "app:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
      },
      "ci": {
        "progress": false
      },
      "test": {
        "browserTarget": "app:build:test"
      }
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
    "options": {
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "browserTarget": "app:build:test"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "ci": {
        "progress": false,
        "watch": false
      }
    }
  },
}
```

My problem is that when I run **'ng serve --configuration test'**, everything works well and the correct environment is loaded (console.log enfironment from src/environment/environment.ts in app.component);

But when I run ng test, the error **"Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "/browserTarget" must be array."** happens. If I put it into an array as asked by the error, the tests runs correctly but without the right environment (the default one is used).

Thanks for your help.